# API to determine whether running on iPhone or iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uidevice

Is there an API for checking at runtime whether you are running on an iPhone or an iPad?

One way I can think of would be to use:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
```

And detect the existence of the string @"iPad" - which seems a bit fragile.

In the 3.2 SDK, I see that `UIDevice` also has a property which is really what I'm looking for, but doesn't work for pre-3.2 (obviously):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom];
```

Are there other ways than checking for the existence of @"iPad" for a universal app?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Checkout [`UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM).

> Returns the interface idiom supported by the current device.
>
> **Return Value**
> `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone` if the device is an iPhone or iPod touch or `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` if the device is an iPad.
>
> [**UIUserInterfaceIdiom**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
>
> The type of interface that should be used on the current device

```
typedef enum {
   UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone,
   UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad,
} UIUserInterfaceIdiom;
```

Comment: Gotcha - I can use respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom) instead of checking for the existence of the string "iPad".  Thanks!

Comment: use the macro - later OS's will respond to the selector, but not necessarily be an iPad.

Comment: Ok, I'm learning. :)  My #fail:

I've been using the simulator to toggle between iPhone and iPad by switching the Active SDK between 3.2 and 3.1 - in which it no longer compiled when the Active SDK is 3.1.  Then I jolted the neurons with some caffeine and plugged the #ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM around it...  

Anyway, thanks for the followup Andiih - and if I've just compounded my #fail to something #worsethanfailure with the #ifdef, let me know. :)

Comment: Just for cross-linking's sake: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576356/how-does-one-get-ui-user-interface-idiom-to-work-with-iphone-os-sdk-3-2

Comment: One caveat: If the iPad user is running an iPhone-only app (as in non-universal) the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM function will report the device as an iPhone.

Comment: @Andiih Would be better to include some source instead of a link.

Answer (score 15):

Just for my reference:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isPhone;

-(BOOL)isPhone {
    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone);
}
```

or use a #define

```
#define IS_PHONE  (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

However, if you're using `isPhone` all over your code, that's generally bad practice. Use the factory pattern and polymorphism to keep your `if` statements contained, so you get objects created for phone or for iPad and then work with those.

**Added**

I'm using this solution all over my code now. It adds a standard factory pattern into the alloc.

```
#define ALLOC_PER_DEVICE()  id retVal = nil; \
                        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass(self);\
                        if (IS_PHONE && ![className hasSuffix:@"Phone"]) {\
                            className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Phone", className];\
                            Class newClass = NSClassFromString(className);\
                            retVal = [newClass alloc];\
                        }\
                        if (!retVal)\
                            retVal = [super alloc];\
                        assert(retVal != nil);\
                        return retVal\
```

Then my allocs look like this:

```
+alloc { ALLOC_PER_DEVICE(); }
```

And I add a subclass called `TheClassPhone` for the phone version.

**Note:** Since there's no multiple inheritance in Objective-C, using inheritance to solve your problems is a bit overrated (i.e., it doesn't work if you have subclasses of subclasses). Nothing like a good `if` when you need it.

Comment: Hi, learner of Objective-C here. Just wondering why it's not necessarily a good idea to say make a utilities class and then add an "isPhone" static method to it so that I can do if([utilities isPhone]) { /* iphone stuff */ }else{ /* ipad stuff */ } throughout my project? Also, why do you define your method as a property?

Comment: utilities class with class methods is fine. I define it as a property because I want to use it that way.

Comment: If your `Utilities` class is a singleton, then you can use `utilities isPhone` otherwise make class methods. Singleton is definitely the recommended way to go. Methods as properties are the same. Objective-C is flexible like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSClassFromString and an iPad-specific class. Read more here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH9-SW3

Comment: -1 really hard to tell what your answering here. Either delete or fix, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check for the presence of the userInterfaceIdiom property, usings respondsToSelector:. If it doesn't exist, we are on a pre-3.2 device, thus not an iPad.
2. If userInterfaceIdiom exists, use it.

**Edit:** ... which is obviously exactly what the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() macro does, so use that instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if you run the app on iPhone or iPad by using the following code:

```
- (NSString *)deviceModel
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);
    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (NSString *) platformString
{
    NSString *platform = [self deviceModel];
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone_2G";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone_3G";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone_3GS";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone_4";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon_iPhone_4";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone_4S";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone_5";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone_5";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod_Touch 1G";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod_Touch 2G";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod_Touch 3G";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod_Touch 4G";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])           return @"iPad_1G";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad_2(WiFi)";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad_2(GSM)";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad_2(CDMA)";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad_3";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad_3(GSM/CDMA)";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad_3(GSM)";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad_3(GSM)";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad_mini_1G";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    else if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
    return platform;
}
```