# How can I detect which system my App Store application is running on?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am developing a Cocoa Touch application for Apple's App store and I want to do some tweaking in the code depending on what device it's running on. How can I tell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [API to determine whether running on iPhone or iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884391/api-to-determine-whether-running-on-iphone-or-ipad)

Answer (score 4):

I've used this in a Universal app to determine if the code is running on an iPad

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
{
    // Do iPad only stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look at `UIDevice` and it's properties.  There is a `systemVersion` string that will work for what you want.