# How can I determine programmatically that my app is running on an iPhone, iPad or iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I just finish my iPhone game using cocos2d. But before I put it on the AppStore, I'd like to make it work on iPad (which have a bigger screen) and iPhone 4 (which have a bigger resolution).
So, how can I determine programmatically that my app is running on an iPhone, iPad or iPhone 4, to be able to use the correct coordinates / images in my game?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean 'programmatically'?

Comment: Well using code I guess? rather than asking the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Between iPad and iPhone** — [Already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884391/api-to-determine-whether-running-on-iphone-or-ipad) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975811/how-can-i-detect-which-system-my-app-store-application-is-running-on) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862140/best-way-to-programmatically-detect-ipad-iphone-hardware) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159951/is-there-a-specific-xcode-compiler-flag-that-gets-set-when-compiling-for-ipad).

**Between iPhone and iPhone 4** — The size reported is *still* 320×480, so you don't need to change anything about the coordinates. Create an `@2x` alternative for the images if you need a high resolution UI image.

Comment: Hey Kenny, could you please tell me what you mean by "@2x" in little more detail?

Comment: @Dave: Say, if you have a 15x27 image `foo.png`, then you create a 30x54 `foo@2x.png`. iPhone 4 will pick up the latter whenever you need `foo.png`. See the SDK doc for detail.