# How to know if we are on an iPad or on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [API to determine whether running on iPhone or iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884391/api-to-determine-whether-running-on-iphone-or-ipad)

Hi,

I'd like to test the device in my application, to know wether I'm on a iPad device or on an Iphone.

is there a easy way to do that ?

thank's au lot

David

Answer (score 2):

All you need is this:

```
UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
```

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-Hardware.m

Note too that any number of search engines will work for this also (SO and google come to mind).  And they will be PHENOMENALLY faster that posting and waiting.  Just saying.