# if (device == iPad), if (device == iPhone)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

So I have a universal app and I'm setting up the content size of a `UIScrollView`. Obviously the content size is going to be different on iPhones and iPads. How can I set a certain size for iPads and another size for iPhones and iPod touches?

Comment: possible duplicate of [API to determine whether running on iPhone or iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884391/api-to-determine-whether-running-on-iphone-or-ipad)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
     // The device is an iPad running iOS 3.2 or later.
}
else
{
     // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

and

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

The macros UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() also works on older iOS versions like iOS 3.0 without crashing.

Answer (score 5):

`UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` is the best solution in your case since your app is universal. But if you are running an iPhone app on iPad than `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` will return `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone`, regardless of the device. For such purposes as that, you can use the `UIDevice.model` property:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].model rangeOfString:@"iPad"].location != NSNotFound) {

    //Device is iPad
}
```

Comment: This is not realiable. As far as I'm aware, the `UIDevice.model` property is equal to the string present in Settings > About and is changable by the user. Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/name

Comment: @KennethJ thanks for the warning but I have checked it and I don't think so. Settings > general > about > Model gives "MD297B/A" for my iPhone 5 and is not editable (on the menu only the field "name" is editable). The API link you gave states that device.model is readonly and @”iPhone” and @”iPod touch” are possible values.

Comment: Yes you are quite right, I was mistakenly looking at "name" rather than "model". I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 2.x you can use the following equalities to determine the kind of device:

`UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone`

or

`UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad`

In Swift 3 for new people coming here.

`if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    \\ Available Idioms - .pad, .phone, .tv, .carPlay, .unspecified
    \\ Implement your awesome logic here
}`

Answer (score 2):

The [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) class will tell you everything you need to know about the device. The [model](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/model) property, for instance, will tell you the model of the device. You can use this to determine which view to use for the current device.

Comment: It's not recommended to use the model property as it's not future-proof.

Comment: That's the first I've heard of this. Can you provide me with a link? If this is the case, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Actually, I heard it on a WWDC session on making iOS apps future-proof. Using the model property gives you a string. If Apple releases a new iOS device that is similar to the iPhone but has another name, say "iPhone nano", the app won't be able to function correctly. I advise using UIScreen's applicationFrame property for this situation. It's analogous to determining hardware capabilities: instead of only enabling the gyroscope on the iPhone and the iPad, it's better to enable it only if Core Motion says so. If once the iPod touch or a future device also supports it, you've got a problem. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UIScreen` class to determine the application's frame.

```
CGRect usableSpace = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
```

The returned rectangle is the screen's size minus the status bar. Don't use the UI idioms for determining available space as they're not future-proof.

By the way, `UIViewController` can resize content views (including scroll views) automatically, as well as provide you with other goodies, such as auto-rotation. Consider it if it's appropriate in your situation.

Comment: Idioms are the way they are now, and it's trivial to change it in the future. They're a lot more clear and meaningful than your suggestion, IMHO.

Comment: @Inspire48: The question is: how can I properly size my scroll view? The easiest way to do that is by using the size the system gives. So, even on a iDevice not yet known, the code wouldn't break, because you wouldn't care about the device (idioms), but only about the display (sizing a scroll view, etc.). Obviously, for many other circumstances, using the idiom is the way to go. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using swift,

```
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
    {
     // device is ipad
    }
    else
    {
     //device is  iPhone 
    }
```

You can also check the UIUSerInterfaceIdiom and choose the device you want to UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad or UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone or UIUserInterfaceIdiom.TV or UIUserInterfaceIdiom.CarPlay