# Added iPad Storyboards, Now: "expected to have a root view controller..."

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard, appdelegate

I've had an iPhone only app, built for the most part with the `Interface builder`.

I have a storyboard for each screensize/device.
In the `AppDelegate`, it selects the correct storyboard and loads it.

I've since redesigned my app and now adding iPad compatibility.

I've added two new storyboards, fixed their size to "iPad Full Screen" and "iPad Pro Full Screen".

I've copied in the existing iPhone Storyboards and ticked the first board as "Is Initial View Controller".
I've also followed [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877113/xcode-storyboard-why-does-the-ipad-storyboard-show-iphone-sized-views) and opened storyboards as source code and updated the target from default to iPad.

When I launch the app on an iPad, i just get a black screen with the following error:

`Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`.

Why is this happening?

This is the only thing I've changed in my `AppDelegate` to select the correct Storyboard:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

UIViewController *initialViewController = nil;
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

    if(result.height == 480){
        NSLog(@"iPhone 3.5 Inch");
        UIStoryboard *i4SB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone35" bundle:nil];
        initialViewController = [i4SB instantiateInitialViewController];
    }
    if(result.height == 568){
        NSLog(@"iPhone 4 Inch");
        UIStoryboard *i5SB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone4" bundle:nil];
        initialViewController = [i5SB instantiateInitialViewController];
    }
    if(result.height == 667){
        NSLog(@"iPhone 4.7 Inch");
        UIStoryboard *i47SB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone47" bundle:nil];
        initialViewController = [i47SB instantiateInitialViewController];
    }
    if(result.height == 736){
        NSLog(@"iPhone 5.5 Inch");
        UIStoryboard *i55SB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone55" bundle:nil];
        initialViewController = [i55SB instantiateInitialViewController];
    }

    //added iPad compatibility
    if(result.height == 1024){
        NSLog(@"iPad Mini(2,3,4) or iPad Air(1,2) or iPad(3,4) or iPad Pro(9.7inch)");
        UIStoryboard *iPadMiniSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPadFull" bundle:nil];
        initialViewController = [iPadMiniSB instantiateInitialViewController];
    }
    if(result.height == 1366){
        NSLog(@"iPad Pro(12.9 Inch)");
        UIStoryboard *iPadProSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPadPro" bundle:nil];
        initialViewController = [iPadProSB instantiateInitialViewController];
    }
}

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

**UPDATED / SOLUTION:**

As Bharat Nakum mentioned below, you can remove the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone` condition.

Of course, you can also add an extra condition for iPad (which is what I did).

It now looks like this:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    //set iPhone device storyboards here
}
else if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    //set iPad device storyboards here
}
```

This is also confirmed as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046539/if-device-ipad-if-device-iphone).

Comment: Dude, for the love of god, learn autolayout!  it is extremely bad practise to have a storyboard for each screen size.

Comment: I hate auto layout. Never seems to look good across all devices. (Plus, for the purposes of this app, it really doesn't matter either way). It is something I'll do in the future though no doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove this condition.

`if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)`

It is true only when device is iPhone.

So, your iPad storyboards are not initializing.

Hope this helps!