# Robovm/LibGDX - How to detect the device family?

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm

I've developed a libGDX game and ported it to iOS using RoboVM. I want to display a certain feature on iPad but it should not be on iPhone. How to detect if the device is an iPad or an iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to test the resolution of the game. As far as I know the iPad and iPhone have different resolutions. This method however isn't ideal, so you should probably use platform specific code to test this.

Take a look at these two SO questions:

[iOS detect if user is on an iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167221/ios-detect-if-user-is-on-an-ipad)

[API to determine whether running on iPhone or iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884391/api-to-determine-whether-running-on-iphone-or-ipad)