# iPhone / iPad universal app orientation

Tags: iphone, ipad, orientation

I am working on the app which is universal app. Now I want to set the orientation for both means When app launch on iPhone then it open in portrait mode and when the app launch on iPad then it open in landscape mode.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
        return YES;
    } else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
  // Rotate to landscape
}
else {
  // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
  // Rotate to portrait
}
```

"[How does one get UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDOM to work with iOS 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576356/how-does-one-get-ui-user-interface-idiom-to-work-with-iphone-os-sdk-3-2)"

Comment: As @Emil implies, you could use the above within your view controllers `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method to control the orientation on a per-device basis.

Answer (score 0):

Also u can use [UIDevice currentDevice].model or [UIDevice currentDevice].systemName to recognise device then in shouldAutoRotate method return interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft for ipad and  interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait for iphone based on device type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding some code to your app delegate per [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628667/different-initial-interface-orientation-iphone-and-ipad-universal-application).

Swift code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft.rawValue | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight.rawValue)
    }
}
```