# Different Initial interface orientation iPhone and iPad universal application

Tags: ios5, ios6

What I want is Portrait orientation for iPhone and Landscape orientation for iPad app.
My app is targeted for > [ios5](/questions/tagged/ios5) 
I searched on web about this but got different answers but not the exact one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I did

For iPhone
[image]

and for iPad
[image]

And for iPad controllers I added below code, this is not necessary for [ios6](/questions/tagged/ios6) applications

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by simply adding this code to your app delegate.

Swift code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft.rawValue | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight.rawValue)
    }
}
```